# Adding loop statement to every bit VHDL

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

Hi guys I just want to ask if is it possible to add a loop statement on this code that prints each bit?
if its possible how?

here is the code.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity T10_StdLogicTb is
end entity;

architecture sim of T10_StdLogicTb is
    signal Signal1 : std_logic := '0';    --initial value of Signal1 is 0
    signal Signal2 : std_logic;

    signal Signal3 : std_logic;
begin
    process is
        
    begin
              
        wait for 10 ns;  --remember no process can be left without the wake statement
        Signal1 <= not Signal1;
    end process;
    
     
 
end architecture;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot loop through individual bits `Signal1`, `Signal2` and `Signal3`. But you could convert those three into a 3-bit `std_logic_vector` over which you can loop.

Assuming all your three bits are in a vector called `my_vector`. Use `report` statement to print the value, with the `'image` attribute of the `std_logic` type.

```
for i in my_vector'range loop
    report std_logic'image( my_vector(i) );
end loop;
```

Comment: I would like to ask if how do you put the three bits in a certain Variable?

Comment: You can use the concatenation operator to concatenate bits into a bit vector.